# Java: listening from socket while running other processes

Tags: java, sockets, java-threads

I need two java applications to communicate across two computers. One is a front-end displaying information and taking user inputs, the other is a server storing it at the end of a session. The server also has an interface to add/remove users from the system.

I've gotten each application to work on their own, and I've gotten the communication set up to work on its own as well.

Now that I have to combine the modules I've run into an issue I can't seem to solve.

The "server" part of the communication is running in a while(true) loop waiting for packages. This makes it a bit hard to integrate it into the other applications.

I've been reading about Threads, thinking I'd "just" do that, but the complexity has me a bit baffled at the moment so I was hoping someone here could help me get going.

Here's the code in the Server class.

```
private String[] str = new String[4];
private String sentence;
private InetAddress IPAddress;
private int port;

private byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
private byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

private DatagramSocket serverSocket;

private void listen(int serverPort) {
    try {
        this.serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort);

        while (true) {
            receivePackage();
            splitPackage(this.sentence);
            sendConfirm();
        }

    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        System.out.println("UDP Port" + serverPort + "is unavailable.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

private void sendConfirm() {
    this.sendData= "RECEIVED".getBytes();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(this.sendData, this.sendData.length, this.IPAddress, this.port);
    try {
        this.serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void receivePackage() {
    this.receiveData = new byte[1024];

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(this.receiveData, this.receiveData.length);

    System.out.println("Waiting for packet...");
    try {
        this.serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        this.sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());

        this.IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
        this.port = receivePacket.getPort();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void splitPackage(String sentence) {
    this.str = sentence.split("\\+");
    for (String s: this.str) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your Server class implementing Runnable, and put your loop in a run() method (overrided from Runnable).

Once done, you'll juste have to create your Server, and start it with : `new Thread(yourServerName).start();`

By doing so, your server will run "in the background" and listen to entering communications, allowing you to run other processes at the same time.